# How to have a filter in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, filtering

I have a `ContourPlot`, which I can successfully plot. However, I would like to filter values for which `f < 0.5`. I see in the `ContourPlot` documentation it is possible to filter specific values such a `f == g`, and I can plot it too.

Is there a way I can make it plot in a way in which `f > g`?

I saw `ContourDetect` works for this, but I cannot add labels and axes in `ContourDetect`.

Comment: You should be able to simply set `PlotRange -> {0.5, All}`

Comment: Thank you it works! But what if I want to make all the values in that region ({0.5, All}) have the same color?

Comment: Then I would suggest `RegionPlot` instead, e.g. `RegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] > -0.5, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*Putting my comments into an answer, since they seem to have answered the question*</sub>

I you don't want to show certain parts of the `ContourPlot` based on `z` value, you can use [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html):

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, All}]
```

[image]

If you simply want to show the region where a given condition is true (e.g. where the function is bigger than some value), use [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html):

```
RegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] > -0.5, {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let `h[x,y]` be `f[x,y]-g[x,y]` and set `Contours->{0}` and  `ContourShading -> {None, Red}` we can draw the region `f[x,y]>g[x,y]`.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 1;
g[x_, y_] := x*y;
ContourPlot[f[x, y] - g[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> {None, Red}]
```

[image]

For `Sin[x] Sin[y]` and `-0.5` we can set `Contours->{-0.5}`

```
fig1 = ContourPlot[Sin[x]*Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-.5, All}}];
fig2 = ContourPlot[Sin[x]*Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
   Contours -> {-.5}, ContourShading -> {None, Red}, 
   ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3.5], Cyan}];
GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}]
```

[image]